# Part of PHP form not working

Tags: php, html, forms

so I have a problem, if I keep the "business" part in the code the form doesn't work without it, it works!

```
    <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<!-- This part breaks the code -->
<div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label for="business">Promo Code</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Promo Code" id="business" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter promo code here, if you don't have one enter 0.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
 <!-- If I remove this part it works -->

                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label for="message">Message</label>
                                <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message and Zip code goes here" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

So if I run the html code without the part that says "it breaks the code" and without "business" on the php side it runs just fine and I receive an email. Its just that with that field enabled I don't receive the email :/

PHP side:

```
<?php
// stuff over here
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       || 
   empty($_POST['business'])   ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$business = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['business']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// here goes the email part
$to = 'email@yahoo.com'; 
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nBusiness: $business\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@site.com"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: `if you don't have one enter 0` A `0` is considered empty. If that isn't what you mean by `breaks the code` describe that more.

Comment: None of your inputs have `name` attributes. I don't see how it works either way.

Comment: @chris85 I changed that 0 to none, still doesn't work.

Comment: I guess I jumped the gun too quick. See @Barmar's comment and/or update the code if this is not your actual code.